# Как заполнить массив JS последовательностью чисел?

Tags: javascript

Как заполнить массив JS промежутком чисел? То есть:

```
let x = [
1..100(массив от 1 до 100)
]
```

Comment: `Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_ ,i) => i + 1)`, либо `Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => i + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
function* range(s, e) { while (s <= e) yield s++ }

console.log([...range(1, 5)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```js
let x = [].map.call('_'.repeat(100), (a,i)=>i+1)

console.log(x)
```

Еще короче, но начинается с ноля:

```js
let x = [...Array(10).keys()]
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x=[]; 
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
   x.push(i);
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: `while(n--)` покомпактнее будет, наверное

Comment: надо от 1 до 100 значения

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]